# Why MemoryCache use Shallow copy?

Tags: c#, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I'm just wondering, why MemeoyCache use shallow copy to store cache data? any suggestion? If memoryCache use only reference of data, what type of data store in CacheMemory.

```
public static void TestmemoryCacheCloning()
        {
            var memoryCache = new MemoryCache("Test");
            var employee = new Employee
            {
                EmployeeId = 1,
                Name = "A",
                Aaddress = new Aaddress
                {
                    City = "Delhi",
                    State = "Delhi",
                    Country = "India"
                }
            };

            memoryCache.Add("Test", employee, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1));
            Console.WriteLine(employee.GetHashCode());
            var output = memoryCache.Get("Test");
            Console.WriteLine(output.GetHashCode());

        }
```

**Output:**

```
49496962
49496962
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of  a deep copy?  It would only lead to redundancy and probably to errors. What if, when you changed employee.Name after caching it, which Name would be the right one?

Comment: the GetHashCode method should not be relied on for determining reference equality .. use object.ReferenceEquals .. the hashcode should be the same if the instances should be considered equal, i.e. by value. Also, the fact that 2 hashcodes are equal does not mean the instances can be considered the same, only that if the hashcodes are not equal, that the instances can be considered not equal

Comment: Regardless of whether or not MemoryCache uses shallow copies, using `GetHashCode()` to prove that two entities have the same reference is not valid.

Comment: @MaLio & Matthew : your are of course correct but in this small test case GetHashCode() is good enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Without seeing the implementation of Employee, we don't know - `Employee` might implement `GetHashCode()` correctly, in which case two deep-copied instances would return the same hash code.

Comment: Again, formally correct but way of the mark here. And we already know MemoryCache stores references, right?

Comment: @MaLio you are absolutely right, 'GetHashCode()' is not right way to compare 2 object. now I used 'output.Equals(employee)' and result is true.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So every time I'm getting data from MemoryCache and according to request I have to modify that data before sent to the client. although I have created my custom method for deep copy.

Comment: @HenkHolterman this is sample entity but in real I have to append some data before send to client.

Comment: Still unclear what role the cache (or any form of deep copy) should play in "append some data". Do have a look at http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was assuming cache use deep copy (agree I was wrong), If I have 2mb cacheMemory, and MemoryCache use Shallow copy then can I store more than 2mb data in my CacheMemory?

Comment: Even more unclear. 2MB is very small, just make it bigger. Your data can be  removed at any time, you need to be able to reconstruct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133810/discussion-between-pankaj-rawat-and-henk-holterman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) uses a shallow copy?

AFAIK it just stores the object you pass in, and does not do any copying.

So if you make changes to that object afterwards, those changes affect the cached object as well (because they are the same object). Obviously this can cause problems, especially if you are unaware it is happening.

You could write your own cache class, which makes a copy and caches that - then you would need to decide between shallow and deep.

Comment: Let's suppose I have created one object (that occupied 1mb) memory. then I will add that object in MemroyCache so It will not create new memory location for that object, It will use existing memory reference for that object.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.